# Apache PLC4x connecting with Apache kafka , trying connect with Pro sys OPC simulator

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, plc4x

I have a requirement where I need to read the OPC UA data via apache PLC4x and push to Apache Kafka server . I have configured the OPC UA simulator (ProSys OPC Simulator) , Configured my kafka cluster in virtual machine.

```
#The PLC4X connection string to be used. Examples for each protocol are included on the PLC4X website.
sources.machineA.connectionString=opcua:tcp://192.168.29.246:53530

#The source 'poll' method should return control to Kafka Connect every so often.
#This value controls how often it returns when no messages are received.
sources.machineA.pollReturnInterval=5000

#There is an internal buffer between the PLC4X scraper and Kafka Connect.
#This is the size of that buffer.
sources.machineA.bufferSize=1000

#A list of jobs associated with this source.
#sources.machineA.jobReferences=simulated-dashboard,simulated-heartbeat
sources.machineA.jobReferences=simulated-dashboard

#The Kafka topic to use to produce to. The default topic will be used if this isn't specified.
#sources.machineA.jobReferences.simulated-heartbeat.topic=simulated-heartbeat-topic

#A list of jobs specified in the following section.
#jobs=simulated-dashboard,simulated-heartbeat
jobs=simulated-dashboard

#The poll rate for this job. the PLC4X scraper will request data every interval (ms).
jobs.simulated-dashboard.interval=1000

#A list of fields. Each field is a map between an alias and a PLC4X address.
#The address formats for each protocol can be found on the PLC4X website.
jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields=Counter
jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.Counter=3:1001:Integer
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields=running,conveyorEntry,load,unload,transferLeft,transferRight,conveyorLeft,conveyorRight,numLargeBoxes,numSmallBoxes,testString
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.running=RANDOM/Running:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.conveyorEntry=RANDOM/ConveryEntry:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.load=RANDOM/Load:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.unload=RANDOM/Unload:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.transferLeft=RANDOM/TransferLeft:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.transferRight=RANDOM/TransferRight:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.conveyorLeft=RANDOM/ConveyorLeft:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.conveyorRight=RANDOM/ConveyorRight:Boolean
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.numLargeBoxes=RANDOM/NumLargeBoxes:Integer
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.numSmallBoxes=RANDOM/NumSmallBoxes:Integer
#jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.testString=RANDOM/TestString:STRING
```

[image: Screen shot Error]
[image: simulator data]

Help me solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that it is trying to match the PLC4X connection string to the endpoint string returned from the Prosys Simulation Server.
The Prosys endpoint string can be found on the status tab of the Simulation Server. Converting this to the PLC4X connection string format, the connection string should be.

```
opc.tcp://192.168.29.246:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer
```

Just looking at the config file, there also seems to be an issue with the address

```
jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.Counter=3:1001:Integer
```

This should probably be

```
jobs.simulated-dashboard.fields.Counter=ns=3;i=1001
```

Comment: I cloud able establish the connection  between ProSys Simulator and PLPC4x in the localhost using 127.0.1.1 IP, when I try connect with external system IP , I am getting the exception at isSecure Channel. I feel it has to something to do with certificate , can you please suggest